# Java Date Parsing Timezone causing parse error

Tags: java, date, string-formatting

I'm receiving a ParseException with the following code and I can't seem to fix it:

```
String date = "Tue Mar 13 2012 10:48:05 GMT-0400";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzX"); //Tried zzzZ at the end as well
System.out.println(format.parse(date));
```

If I take out the -0400 and the X (or Z) at the end of the SimpleDateFormat things work fine, but once it's in the code, it simply doesn't work.  What symbol should I be using instead?  I'm using Java 7.

Here is the parse error I receive:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Mar 13 2012 10:48:05 GMT-0400"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Mar 13 2012 10:48:05 GMT-0400"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at com.throwaway.parse.DateParsing.testDate(TestDate:17)
```

Comment: `ParseException` I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GMT` part of `GMT-0400` of your string is causing the problem.
The `Z` (or `X` in java 7) parameter is only matching `-4000`. You have to escape `GMT` by using single quotes like this :

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.US);
```

Note that it's also a good practice to put a `Local` in your DateFormat. Without it your code won't work in other countries (like here in France...).

Comment: This works, but I'm not so sure I can always count on the time zone returning GMT, someone might switch a server setting and I could get EST or PST or whatever the case might be.

Comment: I think youre timezone format "GMT-0400" is equal to the common "-0400" where "GMT" is implicit.When describing a timezone using hours and minutes it's always diffrence with GMT as reference. Something like "EST-0400" would be a very strange way to express a timezone. Also if you controle the way to string is generated you can change the timezone format to make it less ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

Three issues all dealing with mixed usage. Either:

1. Use a single lower-case "z" and a ":" separating your hour and time in the time zone when using "GMT(+/-)hh:mm", or
2. Use a single upper-case "Z" and drop the "GMT" from your timezone, and you can use the "(+/-)hhmm" format, or
3. Use a single upper-case "X" and still drop the "GMT" but you can use any format of the hhmm zone.

From the Javadoc:

- z    General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
- Z    RFC 822 time zone   -0800
- X    ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `zzzz` could only parse "GMT-04:00" style strings. Your example can be parsed with this pattern: `EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either.  If I take out the -0400, and remove the X or the Z at the end of my original format the date parses just fine.

Answer (score 0):

use `"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzZ"`.
`zzz` is for `GMT` and `Z` is for `'RFC 822 time zone'` please refer

[Check this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I'd already tried that, I should make that a bit clearer in the question.

Comment: if u can put a white-space between GMT and -0400 u will be able to parse the date, whats the source of ur input string?

Answer (score 0):

If you always expect your timezone to be represented that way, you could put "GMT" in single quotes in your format string to prevent it from being parsed:

```
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XX
```

It's a bit weird that none of the built-in formats can parse it though.  Perhaps the Javadoc is incorrect when it lists `GMT-08:00` as an example of `z`?