# Issues parsing a String into a Calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

When I try the following code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
    try {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        calendar.setTime(sdf.parse("Sun Feb 22 18:02:51 FET 2015"));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I systematically get

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Feb 22 18:02:51 FET 2015"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at foo.Sample.main(LogEntry.java:131)
```

I realize that my issue is the FET timezone. That is a valid timezone. I have tried different things including using `Locale.English` but to no avail.

My issue seems to be due to the timezone as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16871410/1021725).

#### EDIT

The following does not work either

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Here is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703729/java-date-parsing-timezone-causing-parse-error) I found but didn't help me.

Comment: You haven't fixed all your references to the `FET` timezone. This website http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/fetsays to use `MSK` in place of `FET`

Comment: @chengpohi I use Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't seem to support FET.

Use [MSK](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/fet).